# Puzzle about a deaf,dumb and a blind person

Tags: lateral-thinking

A deaf person stole a blind person's hen and a dumb person  saw  him stealing.How can the dumb person convey this to the blind person?

Comment: Not sure what else to tag it

Comment: I had no idea dumb means mute. I only knew the `stupid` meaning of it.

Answer (score 1):

If we go by just the rules, then there is nothing we can do.  The blind person can only hear things, and dumb person can't say anything.

We have to think outside the box for this one.

Lets assume that the blind person knows Braille.  Then the dumb person could write out his communication in Braille for the blind person.

Alternatively, the dumb person could use some "text-to-speech" app on his smart phone.

Or guide the blind persons hand to the location of the missing hen and let him figure it out.

Or find someone to act as an intermediary and translate the dumb persons writing to speech.

Or if they both know morse code, the dumb person can tap out the message.